# Facebook privacy policy not allowing messages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ok a simple question I think. I find it weird that Facebook's privacy policy says no prefilled message should be included when posting a photo through their API. In "2. Give people control" it states:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message
>   parameter of posts with content a person or business didn’t create,
>   even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing. You
>   may use our Share Dialogs to prefill a single hashtag in a post, but
>   don't prefill any content a person or business didn't create via the
>   API.

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

But in their documents you can quite clearly add a message:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/Facebook/5.0.0. At the bottom of the page it shows how you can include a message when posting an image.

```
// Upload a photo for a user
$data = [
  'message' => 'A neat photo upload example. Neat.',
  'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('/path/to/photo.jpg'),
];
```

Can anyone confirm that it's possible or not possible to use the 'message' variable when posting an image?

Maybe I'm missing something but it seems like a conflict that Facebook say they don't wan't messages posted through their API even though they provide the tools to do so.

Comment: Did you run it? What happened?

Comment: They aren’t saying _“they don't wan't messages posted through their API”_ – they are saying, if you include a message, it has to be generated by the user, and must not be pre-filled by your app. So if you have a form for the user to input the data they want to post, and one of the fields is for a message - then your app is allowed to take that form input and post it via API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a privacy issue not a programming question

Comment: @ZacBrown yeh I got it through the review process by getting rid of the prefilled message we had. I had a request to include it back in so I wanted to clarify. Thanks for the responses guys.

Comment: Read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill. The ability to set a message is to support stuff like a custom posting dialog, but the user must type it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you are not allowed to prefill it. For example, by presenting an empty (!) input field where the user can enter the message.

In other words, the user has to write 100% of the message.

If you do prefill it, you will not get through Login Review with the `publish_actions` permission.